# RaisePostBackEvent called on wrong control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, custom-controls

I have spent two days with another colleague investigating this. I was surprised as most solutions discussing this problem either have the wrong solution or a solution that works, I think, for the wrong reasons.

We have a custom button control that needs to raise a ServerClick event when it is pressed. Here is the  summarised code:

```
public class MyButton : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    protected HtmlGenericControl _Button;
    protected string _OnClick = "";
    protected string _Name;
    public event EventHandler ServerClick;
    // etc...    

    public MyButton()
    {
        Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        _Button = new HtmlGenericControl("button");
        Controls.Add(_Button);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        _Button.Attributes.Add("id", string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Name) ? base.ID : _Name);
        _Button.Attributes.Add("name", _Name);

        // etc...

        _OnClick = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "");
        _Button.Attributes.Add("onClick", _OnClick);

        // etc...

        ID = String.Empty;
        Name = String.Empty;
        AccessKey = String.Empty;
        TabIndex = -1;
        Width = Unit.Empty;

        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected virtual void OnServerClick()
    {
        if (this.ServerClick != null)
        {
            this.ServerClick(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        this.OnServerClick();
    }
}
```

On the browser end the code uses two of these buttons

```
<form>

    <!-- etc ... -->

    <div class="row actionBar">
        <PGSC:MyButton Name="btnAccept" ID="btnAccept" LabelID="3244" TabIndex="70" runat="server" OnServerClick="AcceptClickHandler"/>
        <PGSC:MyButton Name="btnClose" ID="btnClose" LabelID="349" OnClick="window.returnValue=frmMMD.hdnMmdId.value;window.close();" TabIndex="80" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**The Problem:**
The event is not raised on the accept button. Debugging reveals that `RaisePostBackEvent` is called but on the Close button, which does not have a `ServerClick` handler attached, hence nothing happens. No event handlers get called.

**Notes:**

- The problem is not seen if there is only one MyButton on the page.
- If the buttons are reordered such that the accept button is the last on the page, it starts working.
- Moving the buttons outside of the form tag causes events to work as expected, and the accept buttons event handler is called correctly.
- Implementing `IPostBackDataHandler` and calling `RaisePostBackEvent()` from `IPostBackDataHandler::RaisePostDataChangedEvent()` causes the event to be raised correctly on the accept button when inside the form tag.
- Calling `RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(btnAccept)` during PageLoad routes events correctly to the accept button.

**The Question:**

What is the correct solution from the ones that work above? Or is there another solution? We need it to work such that multiple buttons on the page can raise independent click events, without regard to their order or position on the page.

**My Thoughts:**

- This problem seems to be discussed here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1074998.aspx?ASP+NET+RaisePostbackEvent+Issues
- One is lead to believe that calling `__doPostback()` with the correct `__EVENTTARGET` should automatically route the event correctly to the button, but this is not happening in reality. It only happens if we also implement `IPostBackDataHandler`. Many solutions on the web seem to point to `__doPostback`, UniqueID etc as the culprit when actually implementing `IPostBackDataHandler` is what seemingly fixes the issue.
- The Control implements `IPostBackEventHandler` but not `IPostBackDataHandler`. I think this is correct because the control does not need to raise any data driven events. So implementing `IPostBackDataHandler` to get it working seems like a hack.
- Using `RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent` is unintuitive and besides will not work if multiple buttons on the page would like to raise events.
- I wonder, how does an `asp:Button` do it?

Comment: public class MyButton : Button

Comment: @EJD, we are not allowed to change the class hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I've simulated a situation. 
Hope it helps. 
There is the MyButton WebServerControl class:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyButton runat=server></{0}:MyButton>")]
public class MyButton : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
            return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["Text"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected HtmlGenericControl _Button;
    protected string _OnClick = "";
    protected string _Name;
    public event EventHandler ServerClick;
    // etc...    

    public MyButton()
    {
        Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        _Button = new HtmlGenericControl("button");
        Controls.Add(_Button);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        _Button.Attributes.Add("id", string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Name) ? base.ID : _Name);
        _Button.Attributes.Add("name", _Name);

        // etc...

        _OnClick = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "");
        _Button.Attributes.Add("onClick", _OnClick);

        // etc...

        ID = String.Empty;
        //Name = String.Empty;
        AccessKey = String.Empty;
        TabIndex = -1;
        Width = Unit.Empty;

        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected virtual void OnServerClick()
    {
        if (this.ServerClick != null)
        {
            this.ServerClick(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        this.OnServerClick();
    }
}
```

I then used my web server control in a project, let's say this is the default.aspx:

```
<div><cc1:MyButton ID="btnAccept" runat="server" TabIndex="70"   OnServerClick="AcceptClickHandler" />
<cc1:MyButton ID="btnClose" Text="Close" Width="256px" LabelID="349" runat="server" TabIndex="80" /></div><div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

And in default.aspx.cs I've implemented simply the event:

```
protected void AcceptClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

The AcceptClickHandler fires only when clicking on the Accept button and not
on the Close button.
Sorry if I didnt get the problem right.

Comment: Thanks, can you describe exactly what you have changed that causes the events to trigger correctly. I tried commenting out `Name=string.Empty`, but that did not help. Also both buttons have to be inside the `<form></form>` tags, not outside.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paste the whole piece of code, the buttons are in the form tags.
`<body><form id="form1" runat="server"><div><cc1:MyButton ID="btnAccept" runat="server" TabIndex="70" OnServerClick="AcceptClickHandler" /><cc1:MyButton ID="btnClose" Text="Close" Width="256px" LabelID="349" runat="server"
   TabIndex="80" />  
 </div><div><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div></form></body>`